# error C2678 in using template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm defining a priority queue and use it on a self-defined struct but I get this error and I don't know how to fix it.

This is my error:

```
error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand 
of type 'const Location' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

my struct Location

```
struct Location
{
   int x, y, value;
   Location(int a, int b);
   bool operator == (const Location& other);
   bool operator < (const Location& other);
};

Location:: Location(int a, int b) {
   x = a;
   y = b;
   value = 0;
}

bool Location:: operator == (const Location& other) {
    return (x == other.x && y == other.y);
}

bool Location:: operator < (const Location& other) {
    return value > other.value;
}
```

Here's my priority queue

```
template<typename T>
struct my_priority_queue {

priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T>> elements;
bool empty()
{
    return elements.empty();
}
void push(T item)
{
    elements.emplace(item);
}
T pop() 
{
    T best = elements.top();
    elements.pop();
    return best;
}
};
```

The main function

```
int main() {
    Location a(0, 0);
    Location b(1, 2);
    Location c(3, 0);
    my_priority_queue<Location> my_pq;
    my_pq.push(a);
}
```

Comment: `bool Location:: operator < (const Location& other) const` <=== note `const` addition. Also belongs on the equivalence operator (and of course in the class-def).

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks a lot, it helps me so much!

Comment: @WhozCraig: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320364/560648

Answer (score 1):

It's as it says.

Your operator cannot take a `const Location` on the LHS, because it is not a `const` function.

```
bool operator == (const Location& other) const;
bool operator <  (const Location& other) const;
//                                      ^^^^^^
```